# Yagarto: Do not include the standard header files

Tags: arm, gcc

I am using a recompiled version of the GCC toolchain for the ARM platform, called Yagarto. The compiler comes with a "standard library" called Newlib, and "standard headers", such as `stdio.h`.

For my project, the licencing of Newlib is not suitable, so I have used a `printf` function from somewhere else. The problem is that it seems the build-in header files are implicitly included in every .c file, and I'm getting the following error:

> c:/yagarto4.6.0/lib/gcc/../../arm-none-eabi/sys-include/stdio.h:182:5: error: conflicting types for 'printf'

Is there a way to have Yagarto not load the standard libraries by default?

Comment: Can you just remove/rename the original standard libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the GCC man page:

> -nostdinc
>              Do not search the standard system directories for header files.
>              Only the directories you have specified with -I options (and the
>              directory of the current file, if appropriate) are searched.
>
> -nostdinc++
>              Do not search for header files in the C++-specific standard
>              directories, but do still search the other standard directories.
>              (This option is used when building the C++ library.)

Other options would be explicitly referencing the header files you do want to include, specifying their directory with -I (which is searched before the standard includes).  Or you could simply remove (or move) the incompatibly licensed headers' directory from the installation.

You may also want -nostdlib to the linker.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there is a way to only ignore the header for `printf`?

Comment: If you are trying to avoid the library, why do you want it's headers?  Even if only for technical reliability I would think you would want to entirely exclude dependence on them, in favor of your own with content you can more easily track.